# Unable to launch docker daemon

Tags: service, docker, daemon, upstart, linux-containers

I have downloaded docker and when I try to launch the docker daemon using the command,
    service docker daemon
I am getting the below error message,

> Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the
>   service(8) utility, e.g. service docker daemon
>
> Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
>   Upstart job

I am already using service command. But the error message is still pointing me to use "service docker dameon" command, as if I am using a different command

Comment: You need to explain more, have you checked this link and done the required steps: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the added `daemon`

Try:
`sudo service docker start`

Answer (score 0):

if your platform supports systemctl, you can also run

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```